# How do I plot .OSM file to a map? 

Tags: google-maps, open-source, maps, openstreetmap

I have downloaded an .osm file from open street map and I want to plot this into an map. What is the best way to do this? I dont want to use Google Maps. Is there any other open source maps available where I can simply use their API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am looking for
[Convert Lat/Longs to X/Y Co-ordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953150/convert-lat-longs-to-x-y-co-ordinates)

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Google_Maps_Example

Answer (score 1):

you can use one of the renderers on this page : http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Renderer#Rendering_Software